# Webpack alias not working for sass "composes" imports

Tags: sass, webpack, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have a few aliases set up in webpack like this:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      data: path.resolve(__dirname, 'data'),
      withStyles: 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles',
      modules: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'modules'),
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'components'),
    },
```

They're working fine when doing `@imports` in sass files at the top of a file:

```
@import '~components/common/css/mixins';

.root {
  @include scale-size(padding-top, 24px, 42px);

...
```

However, when loading with "composes" it says it can't find the module:

```
.bottom-cta {
  composes: cta from '~components/common/css/button';
...
```

However, if using a "normal" path (`../../components/common/css/button`) it works.

Is this expected behaviour? How can i solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try without `~`

Comment: Does not help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-modules-resolve-from-alias

Please note that you'll need to add aliases separately to your config and you will still lose IDE support.